# How do you search through a map?

Tags: java

I have a map:

```
Map<String, String> ht = new HashMap();
```

and I would like to know how to search through it and find anything matching a particular string.  And if it is a match store it into an arraylist.  The map contains strings like this:

1,2,3,4,5,5,5

and the matching string would be 5.

So for I have this:

```
  String match = "5";
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

 Enumeration num= ht.keys();
     while (num.hasMoreElements()) {
        String number = (String) num.nextElement();

        if(number.equals(match))
        {
           result.add(number);
        }

     }
```

Comment: Do you want to search the keys, the values or both?

Comment: What does your map store?  What is the key and what is the value?  You are suggesting that your map contains 1,2,3,4,5,5,5 but keys must be unique, so it can't have 3 keys with the string "5".

Comment: String number = (String) num.nextElement();
Will throw ClassCastException

Comment: The map *wont* contain strings like: 1,2,3,4,5,5,5. By definition, when your code runs, the result list will have at most one object.

Comment: @binil: the way I read his question I see a map like *{a,1}, {f,2}, {c,3}, {j,4}, {i,5}, {r,5}, {d,5}* where the keys are unique but the values aren't.  Then you need to match "5", which gives you three matches (because there are three keys that point to the value 5).  But, yup, the question ain't very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to find in values. So here is something that would work:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
..

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s: m.values()){
        if(s.equals("5")){
            result.add(s);
        }
    }
```

Also, watch for `null`s in your if statement.

Comment: Im getting an error that says "Incompatible types required: java.lang.string found: java.lang.object".  Im passing this through a function like so: public void Equal (Map m ) { ... } is that right?

Comment: ah no, its: public void Equal(Map<String, String> m) {...}

Comment: Good that you figured it yourself. Good luck with Java

Comment: It's a pretty old post, but your code will only result in a array full of '5'. Anyway, as said in another comment, you should use ht.containsKey("5");

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure if I understand you, but I guess you are looking for `containsKey`?

```
ht.containsKey("5");
```

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to find keys from values.

Simple code:

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.keys()) {
    if (targetValue.equals(entry.getValue())) {
        matches.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Better perhaps would be to use a second map for the reverse mapping, or a bidirectional map from a third-party library.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: OK but seen the *"1,2,3,4,5,5,5"* example in his question I take it that *a)* he wants to search on values and *b)* there may be two different keys that have the same value (like three keys having the value 5).  A "traditional" bidir map won't cut it in that case (I think but then all the bidir maps I'm using have both unique keys and values, like Google's Bimap IIRC, so I'm really not sure and I'm interested in info on this).

Answer (score 1):

Map API does not encourage you to use Enumeration any more as its a pretty old interface and was expected to be replaced by COllection interfaces, but legacy is still a concern.

KeySet method returns you a Set back and you can directly use contains method of set for the comparison